# Open file Dialog issue

Tags: c#

I wrote below code for selecting only pdf files but it is not working.

```
OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
fd.ShowDialog();
fd.Filter = "Pdf files (*.Pdf)|*.Pdf";
```

Please help is something wrong in this?

Comment: Try setting the filter before calling `ShowDialog()`. Setting it afterwards will not work as you expect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set the `Filter` **first before opening the dialog**.

```
OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
fd.Filter = "Pdf files (*.Pdf)|*.Pdf"; //this should be before
fd.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Habib has the correct answer, but I felt I would add that you should check the response to `ShowDialog` to ensure that the user didn't cancel the dialog box. If they cancel the dialog box without selecting a file then the `OpenFileDialog` will say the file name is "", which is not going to be useful in the rest of your application.

**Example**

```
OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
fd.Filter = "PDF Files(*.pdf)|*.pdf";
if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
else
{
    // The user cancelled the request to select a PDF
}
```

Hope this helps